# How do I automatically unmount my hard drive when I put my Mac to sleep?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, sleep

I have a misbehaving hard drive that turns itself off when it detects my Mac is asleep. This is bad since OS X doesn't unmount the drive, so I get a nasty error message when the machine wakes up. Is there a way to automatically unmount the drive when the machine goes to sleep?

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the problem I have here: http://superuser.com/questions/7996/os-x-keeps-losing-my-linux-samba-shares
Will give the answer below a try and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SleepWatcher by Bernhard Baehr](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) seems to be what you are looking for.

[Full instructions on how to set it up are available](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080329201951648) on MacOSXHints.com